# haskell-js example breaks in the coffeescript REPL but works from a file or the node REPL

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, read-eval-print-loop

I have been experimenting with the Javascript [haskell-js](https://github.com/arthur-xavier/haskell-js) library, but I stumbled upon a strange behavior of the coffeescript REPL.

With node, the following example works as expected:

```
$ node
require('haskell');
> [1,2,3].map('+1');
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

But with coffeescript, it fails:

```
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.6.1
$ coffee
require 'haskell'
[1,2,3].map('+1')
TypeError: +1 is not a function
at Array.map (native)
at repl:3:15
at REPLServer.replDefaults.eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:27:28)
at repl.js:239:12
at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:55:9)
at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
```

However, it works again when I run it from a file:

```
$ cat test.coffee
require 'haskell'
console.log([1,2,3].map('+1'))

$ coffee test.coffee
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Compiling to test.js results in the following file:

```
$ coffee -c test.coffee && cat test.js
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.1
(function() {
  require('haskell');
  console.log([1, 2, 3].map('+1'));
}).call(this);
```

Now I'm confused. Isn't that what I tested? (The `console.log` wrapper also does not make any difference in the REPL.)

Can you please help me to understand why it doesn't work in the coffeescript REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I repeat your case using `nesh` shell, I get the same error

```
1800:~/myjs$ nesh -c
CoffeeScript 1.7.1 on Node v0.10.1
....
coffee> [1,2,3].map('+1')
TypeError: +1 is not a function
```

But when I run directly with the `coffee` REPL, it works fine

```
1802:~/myjs$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.7.1
1802:~/myjs$ coffee
coffee> require 'haskell'
...
coffee> [1,2,3].map('+1')
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

In the case where it works

```
coffee> console.log [1,2,3].map.toString()
function () {
        var args, fn;

        fn = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
        return _method.call.apply(_method, [this, fn.toFunction()].concat(__slice.call(args)));
      }
```

where it does not:

```
coffee> [1,2,3].map.toString()
'function map() { [native code] }'
```

In other words, the `haskell` version of `.map` has not replaced the native one.  So we need to examine how `haskell` is loading.  `nesh` without the `coffee` overlay also has this load problem.  I bet updating your `Coffeescript` will solve the issue.

edit:

`haskell` installs itself by modifying `global`.

There was a pull request in coffee about 6 months ago (between 1.6.3 and 1.7.0), https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/3150
that addresses the use of 'global' context in the REPL
"Make the REPL use the global context to be consistent with the node REPL."

Comment: Could be, my coffeescript version is 1.6.1 (I edited my post). I will give it a try when I have access to an updated coffeescript version.

Comment: The `package.json` for `haskell` specifies `"coffee-script": "~1.6.2",`.  It's written in coffee.  https://github.com/arthur-xavier/haskell-js

Comment: Confirmed. It works fine on more recent coffee-script versions.